# Creating query with case statement in where clause

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a large stored procedure that pulls data for a report. I am trying to use one of two different values in a `WHERE` clause depending on certain criteria. I cannot figure out how to use a `CASE` statement to get this done, I keep getting errors in the `THEN` part. Below is what I'm trying to do, it's a small portion of the larger stored procedure. So what I am looking for is where `dlp(DATETIME)` is newer than `dlc(DATETIME)` I want to use `dlp` to evaluate with the `@AgeStart` and `@AgeEnd` parameter, if not then use `dlc` to evaluate with `@AgeStart` and `@AgeEnd`.

```
@AgeStart INT
@AgeEnd INT

SET @Recovery = (
SELECT SUM(ISNULL(M.Paid1, 0))
FROM Master AS M
WHERE M.Status IN ('xxx','yyy')
  AND CASE
    WHEN COALESCE(M.dlp, '2000-01-01 00:00:00') > 
         COALESCE(M.dlc, '2000-01-01 00:00:00') 
    THEN DATEDIFF(dd,M.Received,M.dlp) 
      >= @AgeStart AND DATEDIFF(dd,M.Received,M.dlp) <= @AgeEnd
    ELSE DATEDIFF(dd, M.dlc, M.Received) 
      >= @AgeStart AND DATEDIFF(dd, M.dlc, M.Received) <= @AgeEnd
  END
  AND M.Balance >= @OrigBalanceMin AND M.Balance <= @OrigBalanceMax
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a case statement, you can just nest them in parentheses and use an `OR` conditional.  I *think* I got all my parentheses lined up:

```
WHERE M.Status IN ('xxx','yyy')
    AND 
    /* Your updated case statement starts here */
    (
        (
            COALESCE(M.dlp, '2000-01-01 00:00:00') > 
                COALESCE(M.dlc, '2000-01-01 00:00:00') AND 
            DATEDIFF(dd,M.Received,M.dlp) >= @AgeStart AND 
                DATEDIFF(dd,M.Received,M.dlp) <= @AgeEnd
        ) OR (
            COALESCE(M.dlp, '2000-01-01 00:00:00') <= 
                COALESCE(M.dlc, '2000-01-01 00:00:00') AND 
            DATEDIFF(dd, M.dlc, M.Received) >= @AgeStart AND 
                DATEDIFF(dd, M.dlc, M.Received) <= @AgeEnd
        )
    )
    /* Your updated case statement ends here */
    AND M.Balance >= @OrigBalanceMin AND M.Balance <= @OrigBalanceMax
)
```

Comment: Good stuff, I was overcomplicating matters.  Thanks a bunch for your help!